# Segmentation fault inside while loop

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, segmentation-fault

In this code, when I replace i+1 with j+1 in the while loop it gives segmentation fault.I don't understand why since the values
of both the variables is same.

This code snippet is for finding the minimum number of swaps required to sort an unordered array consisting of consecutive integers in ascending order.

```
int minimumSwaps(int n, int* a) {
int i=0,j=0,temp=0,swap=0;
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    if(i+1!=a[i])
    {
        j=i;
        while(a[j]!=i+1)
        {
            j++;
        }
        temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=temp;
        swap++;
    }
    else 
    {
        continue;
    }

}
return swap;
}
```

Comment: which i+1 are you talking of replacing there are two in the code? perhaps you could state more clearly.

Comment: Will the array always contain the number 1 ? Can you show us how you call the function?

Comment: Quote: "when I replace i+1 with j+1 in the while loop it gives segmentation fault.I don't understand why since the values of both the variables is same." What do you mean by this? The variables `i` and `j` are **not** the same!

Comment: And ... why would you want to replace `i+1` with `j+1` ? It makes no sense... you are searching for the element with value `i+1` so why replace with `j+1`

Comment: @Siddharth-Soni the second one in the while loop

Comment: @4386427 the array will always contain the number 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two locations where you could replace `i+1` with `j+1`. If you are referring to the second location,

```
while(a[j]!=i+1)
{
  j++;
}
```

the condition on the while loop will continually become a higher value (every iteration `j+1` becomes a higher valuer and `a[j]` refers to a different value, so the loop iteration will not end until you try to access outside the bounds of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

> when I replace i+1 with j+1 in the while loop it gives segmentation fault.I don't understand why since the **values of both the variables is same**.

No, the values of the variables are not the same.

```
    j=i;   // Here i and j hold the same value
    while(a[j]!=i+1)
    {
        j++;  // but once you execute this line i and j are no longer the same
    }
```

So changing `while(a[j]!=i+1)` to `while(a[j]!=j+1)` completely change the behavior of the code.

BTW - the correct way is `while(a[j]!=i+1)`

Comment: suppose i=1, then according to j=i value of j is also 1. Then what difference does it make if I write j+1 instead of i+1, because anyways the value is going to be 2(inside the for loop)

Comment: @pranj99 yes the value `j` will go to 2 but the value of `i` will still be 1. So `j` and `i` will be different

Comment: @4386427 imho does not answer nor solve the problem.

Comment: @GiovaLomba It does... When the code use `i + 1` it works just fine (provided the input follows the rules stated). So there is really no "problem to solve" in the code. The issue to "solve" is OPs misunderstanding, i.e. that `i` and `j` is interchangeable. They are not and that is what the answer explain.

Comment: @4386427 I understand your point, maybe the question should be changed to reflect what you said, in order to also be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you should check the input arguments given to your function:

```
int minimumSwaps(int n, int* a) {
   if(n<=0){
      ...
   }

   if(NULL==a){
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

This will avoid you having to deal with wrong input. Then, to avoid unwanted out of boundary memory readings, you should edit the condition of your `while` loop as below:

```
while(j<n-1 &&  a[j]!=i+1){
   ...
}
```